# Is there any way to make the Chat more findable?

Tags: discussion

Seasoned Advice includes a webchat like other SEs.  However, there is no way to find or navigate to the chat except to find a link from some question whose comments have been moved to chat.

Given that we get a lot of "questions" that are really people wanting to chat, it would be great if we could have a very prominent link to the chat on the home page.  Is this something the moderators can add?  If not, can we request it of the SE staff?

Answer (score 3):

All changes to the overall design must be done network wide, so the logical place to lead this kind of discussion would be [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

That said, the link to Chat is available on each and every site, near the bottom, next to the other generic info sources like the Tour and the Help.

[image]

Plus on other menu locations and there are 18 entries regarding chat in the Help Center (although once a user saw that link, they probably found Chat right next to it anyway).

You may also want to consider that our chats are not the main focus of the SE model. Chat is traditionally a side gig to the main show, the fact that you need 20 reputation to talk in chat is another indicator for that philosophy.

Comment: I don't see that menu in my interface.  Is this maybe a case of "visible in mobile, not in desktop?"

Comment: I just checked this in mobile, and the menu you're showing isn't visible to me in any version of the site.

Comment: Erm, look all the way down. Under Related and under HNQ. The screenshot in the answer is from my mobile. Same here on SA Meta.

Comment: Oh.  That's a *lot* of scrolling.

Comment: So, question for you: would you be in favor of the chat link being more prominent?  Because I don't want to request it on Meta-SE if the mods here think it's a bad idea.

Comment: Personally? No. Maybe a tiny bit. But that’s just my private opinion, not a diamond statement at all. I feel we are not a chat site. Featuring Chat very prominently _with_ the rep threshold would have even more users confused and disappointed, _dropping_ the threshold means there’s a good chance of chats being overrun by users that “just want to talk” (fine, we have chatted about a lot of weird issues in the past and some of these chats were highly amusing), but also open the doors to each and every random troll and spammer. I wouldn’t want to moderate that.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use the "Burger Menu"

I have often heard this menu referred to as the "burger menu", but it contains a link to chat:

[image]

It is also found in the same location on mobile.